# Where can I usually find city bikes in Copenhagen?

Tags: transportation, denmark, bicycles

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Which European cities have bike rental stations?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/250/which-european-cities-have-bike-rental-stations)

I've been in Copenhagen a few times now and only managed to find a bike once, and that was probably by luck. Is there a location where they're more likely to be left than elsewhere?

Comment: Related: [Which European cities have bike rental stations?](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/250/which-european-cities-have-bike-rental-stations/)

Comment: Answer is already here: http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/250/which-european-cities-have-bike-rental-stations/267#267

Comment: Not sure if this is a duplicate though, as the question isn't is there a scheme, but instead about how to find docking stations in the scheme with bikes

Comment: It's really hard, I've been in that situation. Usually it's easier to find bikes out from the center, but it's all a matter of luck.