# Good route for a 1-day bike trip around Amsterdam

Tags: netherlands, bicycles, amsterdam

I'd like to take a one day biking trip in Amsterdam in October, when I will be coming there for a conference. Could you recommend a scenic path/trail I could take? Please, if possible, include bike path numbers so I can look them up in my map.

I'm a fairly fit cyclist, so length in the area of 50-60 km should not be a problem, especially considering there aren't many hills in the Netherlands :-).

If you can, also recommend a bike rental which rents sporty bikes as opposed to the usual city bikes most dutch people use.

Comment: I wonder if [Bicycles](http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/) might be the better place to ask...I see you've got an account there, so maybe you've considered this already.

Comment: @NickStauner No, not really. That is about bicycles itself, not about scenic tours. I believe it is much more ontopic here.

Comment: It might be better to make this question a bit more general, i.e. "How to plan my bicycle trip in the Netherlands"

Comment: Note that October is the start of autumn which might have some serious heavy winds. Esp. driving on dikes could be hard.

Comment: Winds in the Netherlands, like all weather features, are rather unpredictable and you can get strong wind any day of the year and are as likely to get little or no wind any time of the year.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

My all-time favourite cycle trip from Amsterdam is one from [Amsterdam, through Durgerdam to Marken](https://www.google.be/maps/dir/Durgerdam,+Nederland/Marken,+Nederland/Amsterdam,+Nederland/@52.4111049,4.931266,12z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m20!4m19!1m5!1m1!1s0x47c60edd7cf980df:0x4052e998e8001613!2m2!1d4.9903771!2d52.3780596!1m5!1m1!1s0x47c61ad0f5d519af:0x425b3c2ce66fb7!2m2!1d5.1032057!2d52.4589926!1m5!1m1!1s0x47c63fb5949a7755:0x6600fd4cb7c0af8d!2m2!1d4.8951679!2d52.3702157!3e1). I added some images in a related [answer](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/6967/141). It has it all. Land below sea level, bucolic places like holysloot and the folkloristic Marken. If condition permits you could consider taking the ferry to Volendam and cycle back to Amsterdam from there

Comment: Definitly a must do. I did that and I recomend it!! Going via Volendam through the ferry is quite nice!

Comment: Did exactly that (including ferry to Volendam)! The trail is really amazing: Flat as pannenkoeken and only a few meters from the shore. We did it on crappy city rental bikes and were still fine because the whole country is so flat. Don't plan on staying in Marken for long, it's pretty touristy. But the route itself was already worth the trip!

Answer (score 4):

I have no personal experience with cycling in that area, but I might can recommend to use this [tool from a Dutch bikers association](http://en.routeplanner.fietsersbond.nl/).

Basically, what you can do, is select a starting point for a round trip, a preferred distance, and some more personal preference, which it will take into account where possible. With a lot of tweaking, I get some [example route](http://en.routeplanner.fietsersbond.nl/#route?locations=n414644&distance=60000&randomseed=472&routetype=75&penalties=1097-1~33,264-5~1000&adjustments=692-1~0.001,627-1~0.001,1128-4~191,1128-5~6,270-2~0.191,264-6~36,357-14~0.063,357-3~0.063,357-6~0.016,357-8~63,357-13~63&preferences=63).

The example route goes south, I think it might be more interesting to [go north](http://en.routeplanner.fietsersbond.nl/#route?locations=n414644,2056469,n400866,n414644&speed=18&avoidoverlap=true&randomseed=91&routetype=75&penalties=1097-1~33,264-5~1000&adjustments=692-1~0.001,627-1~0.001,1128-4~191,1128-5~6,270-2~0.191,264-6~36,357-14~0.063,357-3~0.063,357-6~0.016,357-8~63,357-13~63&preferences=63). As a foreign tourist, you might enjoy [Zaanse schans](https://www.google.com/search?site=&tbm=isch&source=hp&biw=1855&bih=995&q=zaanse+schans&oq=zaans&gs_l=img.3.0.0l10.916.2426.0.3034.7.6.1.0.0.0.85.381.6.6.0....0...1ac.1.49.img..0.7.384.R1k57mmb1k4&gws_rd=ssl) and [Volendam](https://www.google.com/search?site=&tbm=isch&source=hp&biw=1855&bih=995&q=zaanse+schans&oq=zaans&gs_l=img.3.0.0l10.916.2426.0.3034.7.6.1.0.0.0.85.381.6.6.0....0...1ac.1.49.img..0.7.384.R1k57mmb1k4&gws_rd=ssl#q=volendam&tbm=isch) on the route.

Hint: on the maps you can click numbered junctions, to show these. You can use it to plan your route accurately, but don't fear to get lost, there are a lot of below signs all around the country. [(source)](http://designworkplan.com/bewegwijzering/anwb-bewegwijzering-fietsrouteborden.htm)

[image: Junctions]